# Movie about "eggs" which are stasis pods with people inside, and a fountain of youth/immortality?

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

The protagonist was a boy. There was also an old man. There was a few giant "eggs" that seemed to be stasis pods of some kind. One of the eggs opened to reveal a "princess" (not sure if accurate but it's what he says), who speaks of being asleep for years before the boy awakened her. The "princess" then dies, apparently having been in stasis for too long.

There may also be something about a possible fountain of youth or immortality, that apparently turned people into strange creatures.

Edit: The movie was an anime. The animation style was similar to other anime from the 80s. He watched it in the UK on some backwards channel I've never heard of.

Comment: You used the "anime" tag, but there is nothing in your description to indicate that the movie you're seeking is an animated cartoon. Is it or isn't it?

Comment: Except for the "Anime" tag, this sounds an awful lot like the 1985 movie [*Cocoon.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088933/)

Comment: No, definitely not Cocoon, though it does have some of the same elements. It would be helpful though if we had some idea of when this was. "A really small child" is not very definite. Also where, at least language and country.